# Does Firebase set and get run on the main thread?

Tags: node.js, firebase

Do they run on the same thread as the node process or do they run on a different thread? The CPU usage for my node process goes above 100% when I do a lot of sets and gets (and add several event listeners) on firebase. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

There is only 1 main thread in your Node application, all of your code and all library javascript code will run in this thread. When a library attempts to use IO, it may call upon `libuv` which runs in its own thread. Libraries may also have their own C++ bindings. Without knowing what you're doing and how the 3rd party library is implemented, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: My question is specifically about the implementation of the official Firebase library for node.